# Problems to POST chaincode (smart contract) to hyperledger-fabric using API

Tags: ibm-cloud, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I've deployed the hyperledger-fabric service on Bluemix and obtained the credentials from there, one line looks like this:

```
   {"enrollId":"user_type1_0","enrollSecret":"XXXXX","group":"group1","affiliation":"0001","username":"user_type1_0","secret":"XXXXX"}
```

I post the following to the "registrar" REST endpoint:

> Secret: {   "enrollId": "user_type1_0",   "enrollSecret": "xxxxx" }

I get this response:

> {   "OK": "Login successful for user 'user_type1_0'." }

Then I try to register some chaincode using POSTing the following to the chaincode REST endpoint:

> QuerySpec  {
>        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
>        "method": "deploy",
>        "params": {
>            "type": 1,
>            "chaincodeID": {
>                "path": "https://github.com/ibm-blockchain/learn-chaincode/finished"
>            },
>            "ctorMsg": {
>                "function": "init",
>                "args": [
>                    "hi there"
>                ]
>            },
>            "secureContext": "user_type1_0_xxxxx"
>        },
>        "id": 1  }

I get this reponse:

> {   "jsonrpc": "2.0",   "error": {
>       "code": -32000,
>       "message": "Registration missing",
>       "data": "User not logged in. Use the '/registrar' endpoint to obtain a security token."   },   "id": 1 }

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fabric expects that you will provide EnrolmentID as a security context but you are trying to use "ID+Pass".

Can you try to run your deploy command with another SecurityContext value ?

`QuerySpec { "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "deploy", "params": { "type": 1, "chaincodeID": { "path": "https://github.com/ibm-blockchain/learn-chaincode/finished" }, "ctorMsg": { "function": "init", "args": [ "hi there" ] }, "secureContext": "user_type1_0" }, "id": 1 }`

Comment: hi it works - but I don't understand - I'm not providing any secret anymore, so how is this REST call secure then?

Comment: Secret used only once for “registrar” operation in order to generate ECert. Then this certificate will be used to sign all your transactions to the network. SecurityContext is necessary to distinguish different users and select appropriate certificate. Such approach simplifies first steps with Fabric, you can use NodeJS SDK to get full control on ECert.